# Hi time how to add time for a root element in xml

Tags: mule, dataweave

dataroot @("xmlns:od" : "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata" , generated :'date')

What are the possible ways to add current date and time in generated place and dataroot is the root element in my xml.

Comment: Could you post examples of the data you have and the expected output one?

Answer (score 0):

You can use any expression that returns a formatted date or time instead of the string 'date'.

Example
%dw 2.0

```
output application/xml
var currentTimeFormated=now() as String {format: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"}
---
dataroot @("xmlns:od" : "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata" , generated: currentTimeFormated) : {}
```

The formatting patters are the same of the java.time package. You can find more examples at https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/dataweave-types#date_format_change